# tideSDK menu not visible

Tags: tidesdk

I am trying out tideSDK, but unfortunately i'm not getting very far.

I am on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5, I have been able to install all installables and I am also able to run the basic HelloWorld sample app.

However, it is supposed to have a menu bar (as per app.js file and screenshot on getting started guide page - http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started),

[image]

but this is not visible for me.

[image]

Help please...

C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's different for the position of menu between windows and mac . On mac, you can find it in the top menu bar